# Removing Brackets from powershell query

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

ive got an Azure related powershell query that creates an array of Service principles, then using this array, it looks up the end date for each service principle and creates a new object using just the service principles displayname and end date. So far so good however the format is off, i have a feeling its because im trying to combine 2 arrays into an object instead of string however i still dont know how to fix it:

```
$sp = get-azadserviceprinciple -DisplaynameBeginswith "new"

foreach($appid in $sp.ApplicationId){
$enddate += Get-azadAppCredential -applicationid $appid
}

New-Object psobject -property @{
Name = $sp.DisplayName
expiration = $enddate.EndDate
}
```

this returns

```
@{newsp}, @{newsp2} {31,12,2022}, {31.12.2022}
```

Ideally it would return

```
    Name            expiration
newsp           31,12,2022 
newsp2          31.12.2022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like below, `$test` in the script is what you want. Also note you have a typo in your command, it is [`Get-AzADServicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-5.7.0)(not case sensitive), not `get-azadserviceprinciple`.

```
$sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplaynameBeginswith "new"
$test = @()
foreach($appid in $sp.ApplicationId){
    $enddate = Get-AzADAppCredential -applicationid $appid
    $displayname = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $appid).DisplayName
    $test += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name=$displayname
        expiration=$enddate.EndDate}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add members to object in foreach cycle

Here is an example:

```
$sp = get-azadserviceprinciple -DisplaynameBeginswith "new"

$obj = @()
foreach($appid in $sp.ApplicationId){
  $enddate += Get-azadAppCredential -applicationid $appid
  
  $obj += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Name="$appid.DisplayName"; expiration="$enddate.EndDate"}
  }
}
```